# Android: How to put a drawable on top of foreign applications?

Tags: android, service, filter, screen, draw

After I installed the `ScreenFilter` App, I wondered how it displays a transparent rectangle on top of all applications.

And now I want to know if it is possible to write an `Service`, which put a drawable on top of the screen, no matter what application is in focus.

Is there any solution for this?